# При изменении позиции старый маркер почему то остается . а новый добавляется

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps, google-api

Есть интервал в котором берутся данные из таблицы в массиве и затем задаются в позицию но почему то маркеры не изменяют позиции ,тоесть старый маркер остается добавляется еще и новый

```
setInterval(function () {
    var locations = [
        ['Elvir',parseFloat($('td').eq(3).html())||0,parseFloat($('td').eq(4).html())||0, 01],
        ['Nicat',parseFloat($('td').eq(10).html())||0, parseFloat($('td').eq(11).html())||0, 5],
        ['SAmson',parseFloat($('td').eq(17).html())||0, parseFloat($('td').eq(18).html())||0, 3],
        ['Arif', parseFloat($('td').eq(24).html())||0, parseFloat($('td').eq(25).html())||0, 2],
        ['Haqquwa',parseFloat($('td').eq(31).html())||0, parseFloat($('td').eq(32).html())||0, 1]
    ]; 

    var markers = [];
    var num_markers = locations.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {  
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });

    };

    for(var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++)
        markers[i].setPosition({lat:locations[i][1],lng:locations[i][2]});

},5000) ;
```

Comment: потому что ты создаешь новые маркеры - каждый раз

Comment: вынеси цикл создания _из_ setInterval

Comment: ПОняяяяяяятно ,а я могу как то из вне цикла обратиться к locations ?

Comment: Так как мне надо чтоб locations тоже в цикле обрабатывлся

Comment: для создания маркеров тебе не нужен `locations`. тебе нужно только количество маркеров, а оно у тебя судя по всему - статичное

Comment: Точно !Спасибо Грундик большое